# How can i spit the input into 2?

Tags: java, input, token

i have an input that consists of any 2 numbers on a single line and there can be an unlimited number of lines, ex.

```
        30 60
        81 22
        38 18
```

I want to split each line into 2 tokens, first token is the number on the left and the second token is the number on the right. What should i do? All help is appreciated.

Comment: Please share your code or at least tell us what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Scanner and System.in:

```
public class SplitTest
{
    public static void main (final String[] args)
    {
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in))
        {
            while (in.hasNext ())
            {
                System.out.println ("Part 1: " + in.nextDouble ());
                if (in.hasNext ())
                    System.out.println ("Part 2: " + in.nextDouble ());
            }
        }
        catch (final Throwable t)
        {
            t.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to receive an input from a user through a scanner, the input can be any 2 numbers on a single line and an unlimited number of lines.

Answer (score 0):

If the input is always setup like that, take a look into String.split()

Answer (score 0):

```
// For just splitting into two strings separated by whitespace
String numString = "30 60";
String[] split = numString.split("\\s+");

// For converting the strings to integers
int[] splitInt = new int[split.length];
for(int i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
    splitInt[i] = Integer.parseInt(split[i]);
```

Comment: the numbers are not always like that.

Comment: @danielp I don't understand. I'm just using the example you posted.

Comment: In the code  you have you put " String numString = "30 60" " but the user can input anything, any 2 numbers. Those numbers in my question are just an example.

Comment: @danielp Ok, your question seemed like you were only interested in learning how to split the string. ethereous seems to have posted the complete solution in his answer.